# How to code a very simple user login in Java?

Tags: java, authentication, methods

I'm doing a coding exercise where I'm basically building a little shop application and I'm very very new to Java

I'm having some trouble though, I want to write a method called `setPrice()` that allows a user to change the price of a `Content` object by logging in and declaring a price

This is the Admin class (it extends user, I'll include that too). The Admin class has some commented out code that I tried to use to invoke the login (I'm not sure this is the right way to go about this though:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Admin extends User {

    //class attributes
    String password;
    int privilegeLevel;
    boolean loggedIn;
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    public Admin(String id, String name, String pass, int level) {
        super(id, name);
        password = pass;
        privilegeLevel = level;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public int getLevel() {
        return privilegeLevel;
    }

//  public void login() {
//      System.out.println("Please enter your password.");
//      String passwordAttempt = console.next();
//      
//      if (password.contentEquals(passwordAttempt)) {
//          System.out.println("Log in successful");
//          loggedIn = true;
//      }else {
//          loggedIn = false;
//      }
//  }

}
```

```
public abstract class User {
    //Content Attributes
    private String ID;
    private String userName;

    public User(String id, String name) {
        ID = id;
        userName = name;
    }

    public void changeName(String newName) {
        this.userName = newName;

    }

    public String getUserID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return userName;
    }



}
```

The piece of code I've been given that's supposed that  has to invoke the `setPrice()` method looks like this: `b1.setPrice(a2.login(), 14.25);`. Where b1 is a `Book` which is an extension of the `Content` class:

```
public abstract class Content {

    // Content Attributes
    private String contentName;
    private String contentID;
    private double contentPrice;
    private int downloadCount= 0;
    private Comment[] comments = new Comment[100];
    private int commentCount = 0;

    // Constructor
    public Content(String ID, String Name, double price) {
        this.contentID = ID;
        this.contentName = Name;
        this.contentPrice = price;

    }

    public Content(String ID, String Name) {
        this.contentID = ID;
        this.contentName = Name;
        this.contentPrice = 0;

    }
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Book extends Publication{
    //attributes
    private String[] authorNames;


    // constructor
    public Book(String ID, String name, double price, String publisher, int numberPages, String[] authors1){
        super(ID, name, price, publisher, numberPages);
        this.authorNames = authors1;
    }

    // accessor methods
    public String[] getAuthorName() {
        return authorNames;
    }

    public String[] getAuthorNames() {
        return authorNames;
    }
    }
```

Basically I can work out what to write within the method, I just can't work out how to let the method accept `a2.login()` as a parameter?

Comment: So before you allow the Admin to set the price , you want to check if the admin is logged in or not?  If I understand it correctly

Comment: How is setPrice() method is getting invoked? Is it on some button click or some other event?

Comment: Yes I'd just like to check whether they are logged in or not by asking them to enter a password and then check it against that listed under the object when it was instantiated.

Comment: At the moment I'd like to write a `setPrice()` method in `Content` that I can call from the Main class by using `b1.setPrice(a2.login(), 14.25);`

Comment: What you can do if it all a console based, in side the setPrice() method , first call a2.login () method which will return true or false based on password is correct or not? So you just pass the price in method like setPrice(float price){ if (a2.login()) {// setPrice} else {// Password not correct}}

Comment: Or alternatively, you can pass 'this' in the setPrice method like setPrice(this,float price) . This way you can get the reference of the object(in this case Admin) which called the setPrice() method. Hope it is clear!

Comment: I'm not sure either of these preserve the `b1.setPrice(a2.login(), 14.25);` structure.
Could you give me an example?

Comment: But why you want to do it that way ? Please help me understand

Comment: Oh, it's a homework task that I'm trying to solve for a class, so they've stipulated that it had to be done that way sadly :(

I feel like the homework task has greatly over complicated the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your `login()` code as below :

```
public boolean isloggedIn() {
      System.out.println("Please enter your password.");
      String passwordAttempt = console.next();

      if (password.contentEquals(passwordAttempt)) {
          System.out.println("Log in successful");
          loggedIn = true;
      }else {
          loggedIn = false;
      }
      return loggedIn;
  }
```

And your setPrice() method as below :

```
void setPrice(boolean isLoggedIn, Double value)
  {
      if(isLoggedIn)
      {
          //set the price
      }
  }
```

Then you can call:

```
b.setPrice(a2.isloggedIn(), 14.25);
```